# react setstate works on second click

Tags: reactjs

Hello i'm having an issue i don't know why but the setState doesn't work properly on the "first click"

i have these states

```
const [selected,setSelected] = useState("");
const [fetched,setFetched] = useState([]);
```

when i click on a div i set the selected state first then the fetched with the data i fetch like this

```
const selectStuff = async (data) =>{
  setSelected(data);
  const response = await fetch(someurl);
  if(response !== undefined)setFetched(response);
}
```

the setfetched doesn't get executed, i have to click on the element a second time for the state to re render, i'm always having this issue when i use multiple setState on the same funcion can someone tell me why? I can't find any answer

Comment: You should perform your side effect (the fetch) using the useEffect hook. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: where does `someurl` come from?

Comment: someurl is just a string like "/saveStuff" i just put someurl to keep it generic